# D3 transformation not applied to multiple <g> elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Do you have any idea why the below code doesn't work? I'm trying to create 3  groups with different y coordinate for each. But as soon as I do it like that the transformation is not applied at all and all the `<g>`s are overlapping at 0,0.

If I change the function to explicit x,y coordinates in transformation it works correctly.

```
    var dataset = [{
          data: 100
        }, {
          data: 200
        }, {
          data: 300
        }];

var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0" + function(d,i) {return i * 100} + ")");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the whole `translate` value in a function:

```
.attr("transform", function (d, i){
    return "translate(0," + (i * 100) + ")";
});
```